# Cloning/Splitting a serial port (COM) port in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, split, cloning

Everything is working with my serial port. I have connected my FTDI converter into my computer, set my COM port...
`ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/wine/dosdevices/COM1`

But now I would like to "clone" this port.

I am using wine to run u-center a GPS visualizer and I have a Linux computer running Ubuntu
Could anyone help?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by cloning a serial port. Do you want several applications to access that port? That shouldn't require any special manipulation. Do you want to connect several serial devices? Then you need several ports.

Comment: Yes, Cloning/Splitting the serial port for multi-application use, which I have tried to do. Sorry I wasn't more specific.

Answer (score 8):

While a previous answer said it cannot be shared, this is partly wrong.

A linux TTY port can be opened with different applications ( if they don't use or check for locks), however data will be consumed by whoever reads first because there is only one buffer, so the data won't be available to both processes. There is some cases where this is ok, and some cases where this is not ok, but generally people don't want this.

Since it is possible to create a TTY from userspace, there is nothing stopping anybody from creating a userspace application that creates 2 virtual/fake serial ports, and connects them to one physical serial port.

[ttybus](https://github.com/danielinux/ttybus) does just that (from the readme):

```
Use case 1: Multiplexing serial input only or output only device attached to /dev/ttyS0, for use with multiple applications.
- step 1: create a new tty bus called /tmp/ttyS0mux:

    tty_bus -s /tmp/ttyS0mux &
    sleep 1


- step 2: connect the real device to the bus using tty_attach:

    tty_attach -s /tmp/ttyS0mux /dev/ttyS0 &
    sleep 1

- step 3: create 2 fake ttyS0 devices, attached to the bus:

    tty_fake -s /tmp/ttyS0mux /dev/ttyS0fake0 &
    tty_fake -s /tmp/ttyS0mux /dev/ttyS0fake1 &
    sleep 1

- step 4: start your application and force it to use the new serial device for input or output

    /bin/foo /dev/ttyS0fake0 &
    /bin/bar /dev/ttyS0fake1 &
```

Note: I had to fork into background all the tty_* binaries by terminating the commands with `&` because the binaries are blocking and a few sleeps to keep the binaries from trampling over each-other.

Good luck!

Comment: there's -d option to run `ttybus` processes in background

Answer (score -1):

Serial port communication is always between 2 devices and **cannot be shared**. Only one application can hold the device at a time. But it is possible to snoop the communication i.e. monitor the data transmission.

Comment: Hmm...I know this but I would like to have like two virtual ports to listen into... i.e Goops and GPS Visualizer

Comment: there's a utility called "socat" which can be used to create virtual COM ports

Comment: Here's an example scenario involving `socat`: http://serverfault.com/a/453141