# Split serial port into two virtual ports

Tags: serial-port, split

This question is related to this post here:

[Cloning/Splitting a serial port (COM) port in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12800/cloning-splitting-a-serial-port-com-port-in-ubuntu)

I followed the steps to make the virtual ports but the problem is that I need full-duplex communications between the real port and the two virtual ones. When I tried this on my system, I was able to send data between the two virtual (fake) ports bidirectionally and send data from either of the virtual ports to the real port. But any data sent from the real port to the virtual ports did not show up at the virtual ports. Is there an alternative approach I can use to split a real port into two virtual ports where all three can communicate bidirectionally?

NOTE: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Note that you are not really "splitting" the port, you are creating an "tty bus" that simulates communication between those. Which is awesome, but if that is not working properly, debug that tty bus code. Or write your own.